# Issue with HTML5 Audio Frequency Animation?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

This is an issue with seemingly just the AnalyserNode in JS (or it's between the keyboard and the chair...).

Basically, I have a properly setup audio file (streams under normal circumstances). However, once I try to hook up the analyzer node between it and the destination, everything goes haywire. The audio does not output and the node always gets 0 or undefined in the dataArray. I've been researching this for the past 7-10 hours (with varying amounts of luck) and noticed most people solved it after firing a "canplay" event, but that did not work for me. Any help would be lovely!

As background, this is an IceCast stream, though I don't think it will hurt/change anything.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var audio = new Audio();
audio.id = "audioStream";
audio.src = ; // Snipped our streaming link.
audio.autoplay = true;
audio.preload = "none";

document.body.appendChild(audio);
audio.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
    initAudio(audio);
});
});

function initAudio(audio) {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

    window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

    var context = new AudioContext();
    var analyser = context.createAnalyser(); 
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.85;

    var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio); 
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    analyser.fftSize = 32;
    var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

    var visualisation = document.getElementById("bounceAnimation");
    var barSpacingPercent = 100 / bufferLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style["left"] = i * barSpacingPercent + "%";
        div.style["width"] = barSpacingPercent + "%";
        div.style["height"] = "5%";
        div.className = "lineDance";

        visualisation.appendChild(div);
    }
    var bars = visualisation.children;

    function draw(){
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

        for (i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
            bars[i].style["height"] = (dataArray[i] * -1) + '%';
            if(dataArray[i] != 0) {
                alert(dataArray[i]);
            }
        };
    }

    draw();
}
```

Comment: Could you try a static(downloadable) MP3 file? also, could you try different browsers?

Comment: Analyzer node will require CORS to be fulfilled, not knowing the source link; if from external site (cross origin) and their server doesn't allow CORS you won't be able to use AudioContext (unless you use your own page server as proxy for the stream).

Comment: It's not the analyzer node; it's the MediaElementAudioSource (createMediaElementSource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add:

> audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

and serve your stream with CORS headers.